# Not sure how to test a class that email received feedback

Tags: java, spring, junit, mail-sender

I have following `@Service` class that is used to receive feedback, verify its details based on a list of criteria. If verified send that to its recipient.

I am struggling to write a test case for this class. I know there is no need to test external services using Junit. Like sending email in my case but,

- Whats the best approach to test this class?
- Should I even test it?

  - If not why?
  - If yes how to complete the test case?

**Code**

```
@Service
public class FeedbackServiceImpl implements FeedbackService {

    @Autowired
    private MailSender mailSender;

    @Override
    public boolean sendIt(Feedback feedback)
            throws MailAuthenticationException, CustomException {
        validateEmail(feedback.getEmail());
        try {
            SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
            switch (feedback.getRecipient()) {
            case 1:
                message.setTo("jack@project.com"); 
                break;
            case 2:
                message.setTo("norman@project.com");
                break;
            default:
                message.setTo("hello@project.com");
                break;
            }

            message.setCc(feedback.getEmail());
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(msg);
            mailSender.send(message);

        } catch (MailSendException send) { 
            System.err.println(send.getFailedMessages() + " "
                    + send.getMessage() + " " + feedback);
        }
        return true;

    }

    private void validateEmail(String sender) throws CustomException {
       //make sure provided email is valid
      //this method does verification process against different criteria

    }

}
```

**JUnit**

```
@Test
public void shouldReturnFalseForInvalidFeedbackEmail(){
    MailSender mailSender = Mockito.mock(MailSender.class);
    FeedbackService feedbackSrv = new FeedbackServiceImpl();
    boolean result = feedbackSrv.sendIt(feedback);
    assertTrue(result);
}
```

Comment: I would use a mock and check that 1/ the message is correctly dispatched (ie. if recipient is 1, sent to jack etc) 2/ MailSendException is properly handled 3/ make `validateEmail` `protected` and test it. NB: it's strange that the `sendIt` method always return true

Comment: @Rc If anything goes wrong it throws exception therefore, it just return true. Do you know of any other approach to it? How to test MailSendException? that exception is only passed if MailSender wont be able to send the email.

Comment: http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html might be worth a read (there is a `doThrow()`)

Answer (score 0):

`validateEmail` which can be tested directly using package private visibility. `case` and `catch` can be tested by mocking `mailSender` (and if really necessary also `Feedback`).

and that's it what you can unit test. everything else is integration test. if you're making app to send emails with many different configuration using very different settings then i would test it. if you are using just one configuration and one company smtp server and it's unlikely to be changed in the future then maybe it's not worth to set up automatic mailing tests

Comment: I tried to test the private method to no avail, the question is here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32709784/cannot-test-a-class-that-return-a-customexception

Comment: dont test **private** method. change it to **package private**

Comment: I would like to learn more about reflection, thats why I am testing the private method. Also how to test case and catch? would you give me an example?

Comment: By package private, do you mean default access modifier?