# Cannot test a class that return a customException

Tags: java, reflection, junit

While experimenting JUnit, I am trying to test a simple private method as follows, this method receives a String and make sure it does not include the word 'Dummy' in it.

**I know, it is possible to put the test in the same package** as the class and change access modifier of the method to package but I would like to use reflection to learn that.

```
private void validateString(String myString) throws CustomException {

    if (myString.toLowerCase().matches(".*dummy.*"))
        throw new CustomException("String has the invalid word!");

}
```

I am trying to access the private method through reflection but the test fails! It shows following exception:

```
java.lang.AssertionError:Expected test to throw
(an instance of com.myproject.exception.CustomException and exception 
with message a string containing "String has the invalid word!")
```

Based on answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020719/what-could-cause-java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception), I am catching `InvocationTargetException` as well.

**JUnit**

```
    @Rule
    public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

    @Test
    public void shouldThrowExceptionForInvalidString() {

        thrown.expect(CustomException.class);
        thrown.expectMessage("String has the invalid word!");

        try {
            MyClass myCls = new MyClass();
            Method valStr = myCls.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(
                    "validateString", String.class);
            valStr.setAccessible(true);
            valStr.invoke(myCls, "This is theDummyWord find it if you can.");
        } catch (InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException
                | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException
                | IllegalArgumentException n) {
            if (n.getCause().getClass() == CustomException.class) {
                throw new CustomException("String has the invalid word!");
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: This makes no sense as a test. You are not testing a method, you are only testing the test itself.

Comment: @Stultuske I see would you elaborate on that? how to test the method then?

Comment: if you want to use expectedException, drop the try-catch, and add a throws clause. You don't want to test whether your test throws that Exception but your method.

Comment: Another way: catch(Exception e){ assert(e instanceof CustomException); }
and add a test for the message of the Exception

Comment: @Stultuske I am a bit confused would you please post that as an answer?

Comment: since it's not a complete answer to your question, that wouldn't be recommended. but my point is: this -> thrown.expect(CustomException.class);
        thrown.expectMessage("String has the invalid word!"); will test the Exception thrown by your test itself. What's the point of that?

Comment: When I run the test it returns InvocationTargetException thats why I am catching that. Also I need to catch other exceptions otherwise it wont compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Stultuske in the comments above and would rewrite the test to:

```
@Test
public void shouldThrowExceptionForInvalidString() {

    try {
        MyClass myCls = new MyClass();
        Method valStr = myCls.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(
                "validateString", String.class);
        valStr.setAccessible(true);
        valStr.invoke(myCls, "This is theDummyWord find it if you can.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        assert(e instanceOf CustomException);
        assert(e.getMessage.equals("String has the invalid word!"));
    }

}
```

Or if you want to use ExpectedException

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void shouldThrowExceptionForInvalidString() {

    thrown.expect(CustomException.class);
    thrown.expectMessage("String has the invalid word!");

    MyClass myCls = new MyClass();
    Method valStr = myCls.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("validateString", String.class);
    valStr.setAccessible(true);
    valStr.invoke(myCls, "This is theDummyWord find it if you can.");

}
```

Comment: It works thanks, I just need to know when should I use thrown.expect and thrown.expectMessage then?

Comment: I just edited my answer, and added an alternative way to test using `ExpectedException`